# Swift reload collectionview changes cell order after 4 cells

Tags: swift, reload, collectionview

I have an issue when I add cells within a collectionView which is in a tableView.  The issue is afer I enter 4 new cells the order of the cells change.

```
    @IBAction func addSetButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        numberOfSets += 1
        Constants.Other.numberOfTotaSest += 1
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        print(collectionView.visibleCells.capacity)
    }
}


func myRepsTextChanged(_ tf: UITextField) {
        for x in 0...(numberOfSets)-1 {
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: x, section: 0)
            print("the index path for this failing on the 4th cell is:", indexPath.row)
                
                let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
                let temp = [cell.repsText.text!, cell.tag] as [Any]
                
                if (Constants.Other.duplicateFound == false){
                    Constants.Other.setsFromCollectionView.append(temp)
                }

        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not enough information to debug your issue. Can you include a [mre]?

Comment: You shouldn't prefix variables you're modifying with `Constant`.  For somebody else who doesn't know your code, that's confounding.

Comment: If you reload collection view you should consider reloading table view as the contents of one of its cell changed (may be also the size of the table view cell)